# Permission denied while installing Node.js v14.10.0 on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-20.04, nvm

Hello and thanks for looking at this issue.

So I'm trying to install version node.js v14.10.0. NVM installed without any problems, but when I ran -

`nvm install v14.10.0`

and I got this error

```
Downloading and installing node v14.10.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.10.0/node-v14.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/revolverclyde/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.10.0-linux-x64/node-v14.1
Warning: 0.0-linux-x64.tar.xz: Permission denied
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.10.0/node-v14.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/revolverclyde/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.10.0-linux-x64/node-v14.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.10.0/node-v14.10.0.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/revolverclyde/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.10.0/node-v14.10.0.tar.xz
Warning: : Permission denied
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.10.0/node-v14.10.0.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/revolverclyde/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.10.0/node-v14.10.0.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

UPDATE!!

The error I'm getting above may have something do to with an error I got while installing NodeSource. I'm new to this maybe I'm wrong, but I thought it would be helpful to know anyway.

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 14.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                           
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu focal InRelease                                               
Ign:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease                                                      
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                 
Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                                 
Hit:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release                        
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release       
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Reading package lists... Done       
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

"Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu focal Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]" is the specific error if you don't want to hurt your eyes with the dense readout.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. I am quoting another poster here. I want to give Vishnu the credit.

"I had the same issue. It was due to the lack of "libssl-dev". Run the following command before you start the installation process for nvm

*sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl git-core*"

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission error. You can try to run it with the `sudo` command.

> sudo nvm install v14.10.0

Comment: Thank you for responding. I did that and now I am met with *sudo: nvm: command not found*

Comment: I install nodejs like that: **sudo apt install nodejs**
for changing node version I installed this: **npm install -g n**
you can change node version like that: **n 14.0.0**

Comment: You're running Ubuntu 20?

Comment: I am using 21.10 but I think it will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I also fixed it using Carl Diamond's tip with this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl git-core
```

Then I ran this command:

```bash
nvm install v14.15
```

And that's it, node could be successfully installed.